How to set the name of a custom operator in TensorFlow Lite
I'm trying to create a custom operator in TFLite, wrapping up scipy's lfilter function. The goal being to bind it to its implementation in C++ when invoking the TFLite interpreter (from the equivalent TFLite custom library).
I'm currently able to export the .tflite file but with one caveat: the name of the custom operator is PyFunc. Is there a way to properly set the name of the custom operator? Please note that my goal is to have it encapsulated in a black-box and not a TF-translation of the operation.
Here is the minimal example
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

LFILTER_COEFF_DTYPE = np.float32
LFILTER_DATA_DTYPE = np.float32


@tf.numpy_function(Tout=LFILTER_DATA_DTYPE, name="Lfilter")
def np_lfilter(b, a, x):
    y = signal.lfilter(b, a, x)
    return y.astype(LFILTER_DATA_DTYPE)


@tf.function(
    input_signature=[
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=LFILTER_COEFF_DTYPE, name="b"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=LFILTER_COEFF_DTYPE, name="a"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, None], dtype=LFILTER_DATA_DTYPE, name="x"),
    ],
    autograph=False,
)
def tf_lfilter(b, a, x):
    return np_lfilter(b, a, x)


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Lfilter(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            name="b",
            shape=(3,),
            initializer="ones",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.a = self.add_weight(
            name="a",
            shape=(3,),
            initializer="ones",
            trainable=True,
        )

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update(
            {
                "b": self.b.numpy(),
                "a": self.a.numpy(),
            }
        )
        return config

    def call(self, x, training=None):
        if training:
            ...
            # not relevant...
        else:
            y = tf_lfilter(self.b, self.a, x)
            # For some reason, y comes out with unknown shape
            # Hence we need to set the shape manually
            # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110247/keras-custom-layer-unknown-output-shape
            y.set_shape(x.shape)
            return y

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class ModelLfilter(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filter = Lfilter()

    def call(self, x):
        return self.filter.call(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    CURR_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    input_shape = (1, 32)

    def convert_to_tflite(model, input_shape, name=None):
        if name is not None:
            model.name = name
        tf_callable = tf.function(
            model.call,
            autograph=False,
            input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(input_shape, LFILTER_DATA_DTYPE)],
        )
        tf_concrete_function = tf_callable.get_concrete_function()
        converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions(
            [tf_concrete_function], tf_callable
        )
        converter.allow_custom_ops = True
        tflite_model = converter.convert()

        with open(os.path.join(CURR_DIR, f"{model.name}.tflite"), "wb") as f:
            f.write(tflite_model)

    # SVF
    lfilter = ModelLfilter()
    lfilter(tf.zeros(input_shape))
    convert_to_tflite(lfilter, input_shape, "lfilter")

To which I get the output:
W0000 00:00:1733157983.471392    8472 tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc:392] Ignored output_format.
W0000 00:00:1733157983.471771    8472 tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc:395] Ignored drop_control_dependency.
2024-12-02 17:46:23.584285: W tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/flatbuffer_export.cc:3474] The following operation(s) need TFLite custom op implementation(s):
Custom ops: PyFunc
Details:
        tf.PyFunc(tensor<3xf32>, tensor<3xf32>, tensor<1x32xf32>) -> (tensor<*xf32>) : {Tin = [f32, f32, f32], Tout = [f32], device = "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", token = "pyfunc_0"}
See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom

And here is a screenshot of the model architecture from Netron (note that the b and a weights' names were also not properly serialized).
I've tried following the official example from the documentation but it wasn't of much help, because the export in this case generates an operator based on the already existing tf.atan
